# how to protect the android SDK and communication between sdk and sdk server

Tags: android, security, sdk

I'm implementing a SDK on Android to provide some functions(get app input and send to server and get back response and give the app) to other public developers,SDK need to communicate with a server, how to guarantee the security:
1)between SDK and SDK server
2)How to avoid the SDK been cracked, or the SDK server can identify the SDK cracked?

Many Thanks